# Python - How can I pass variable in Flask when clicked on a button

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a Flask project that has two pages (firstpage, secondpage). The first page has two buttons. When a user clicks on one of them, it should send a variable (variable name is value) with text to the second page. The second page should display message depending on what button the user clicked in the first page. But my program is always printing the second value even when the first button is clicked. If I declared the variable global, can I use it in the secondpage?

My html code looks kind of like this:

```
<form action="/firstpage" method="post">
    <div><h2 class="header">Click one button</h2></div>
    <div class="pickitem">
        <button class="btn one" name="btn-one" type="submit">ONE</button><br>
        <button class="btn two" name="btn-two" type="submit">TWO</button></div>
</form>
```

and my Python code looks like this:

```
var value=""
@app.route("/firstpage", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def mymethod():
value = ""
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.form.get("btn-one"):
        value = "uno"
    else:
       request.form.get("btn-two"):
       value = "dos"
    
    print (value)
    return render_template("secondpage.html")
else:
    return render_template("firstpage.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an hidden `input` field for this.

HTML:

```
<form action="/firstpage" method="post">
    <div><h2 class="header">Click one button</h2></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="btn-pressed" class="hidden-field">
    <div class="pickitem">
        <button class="btn one" name="btn-one" type="submit">ONE</button><br>
        <button class="btn two" name="btn-two" type="submit">TWO</button></div>
</form>
```

Change its value depending upon the button clicked.

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // do not process if the clicked element is not a form button
    if ( ! e.target.matches('form .btn') ) return;

    // prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    // change hidden field value
    let field = document.querySelector('.hidden-field');
    field.value = e.target.getAttribute('name');

    // submit the form
    e.target.closest('form').submit();
});
```

Then in Python, you can get the value through the name `btn-pressed`

Python:

```
request.form.get("btn-pressed") # to get the hidden field value
```

Comment: I am not using JS. It tried the html code and added this in py python file: value = request.form.get("btn-pressed"). value is not getting anything assigned to it

Answer (score 0):

A few syntax errors you might need to fix.

- It seems like you are mixing up different programming languages. In the first line, you entered `var value=""`. Try to remove the `var`.
- Make sure your indentation is correct! Indent the block from `def mymethod():` to the bottom.
- Remove the colon from the line `request.form.get("btn-two"):`. Did you mean `if request.form.get("btn-two"):` instead?

Apart from that, the reason `value` ends up not being either "uno" or "dos" is because of the if-statements in the code. To fix the issue, change them to:

```
if list(request.form)[0] == 'btn-one':
```

Why does this work? The `request.form` looks like this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict(['btn-one', ''])
```

Transforming this into a list (i.e., getting its keys, which is either `btn-one` or `btn-two`) and taking the first item will tell us the button pressed.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I added var by mistake and the indentation was messed up when I pasted here. I tried following the example you mentioned by using list.                                                                                                                       if request.method == "POST":
        if list(request.form)[0]== "btn-one”:
            value = “uno”
        elif list(request.form)[1]=="btn-two”:
            value = “dos”
 print(value).                                  Error is list(request.form)[1] == "btn-two":  IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Try `list(request.form)[0]=="btn-two”` instead :)

Comment: I am doing that and getting the value. But I am having trouble passing this value to the next page. I tried passing to second page like this:                                          
return render_template("secondpage.html", value = value)                                                               But the second page is not recognizing this value.

Comment: No worries, this works for me: session["value"]=value.  Thanks!